# Is app(FQCN); enough to create a service in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, singleton, laravel-8, soa

I'm new to Laravel, having mostly worked with Symfony.

Recently, I saw a piece of code that looked something like this:

```
<?php 

namespace MyApp\SomeNamespace;

use MyApp\UserInteraction\Filter;

class MyClass {

    public function myMethod(){

        $filter = app(Filter::class);

        ...
```

I assume this does something like create or retrieve a singleton. Assuming this is standard practice in Laravel, and not something specific to the app I was looking at, are there any additional steps needed to register a service?

(In Symfony, we would usually have an attribute, a few lines of XML or some YAML that would define service attributes. I tried looking into the `helpers.php` file to see what was going on, and while this gave me some idea of what the `app()` function might be doing, it didn't tell me whether there are additional steps needed to register a class as a service in Laravel.)

While I looked at several other questions and tutorials to see what they said, they all referred to an `app.config` file that isn't present in this application. So I assume the situation has changed in later versions of Laravel.

Comment: To use the `Filter` class, you would need to `import` that class by either adding `use` on top of the file(below the namespace) or change `Filter` to `App\Path\To\Filter`

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the question to show that a `use` statement was present in the app.

Comment: The use of `use` keyword at the top is a PHP OOP keyword. I think it is symfony that is special to use yml files.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/keyword_use.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not wrong the Laravel will automatically resolve your Service that you want to inject:

```
class ExampleController
{
    // The ExampleService will be automatically resolve
    public function __construct(ExampleService $service) {}
}
```

The `app()` helper returns an instance of Laravel Container but if you add an `FQCN` inside it as a parameter it will resolve that class:

```
app(); // it will return a instance of container

app()->make(Filter::class); // it will resolve the Filter::class

app(Filter::class); // ^ the same as the above
```

If you want to bind a service class to an interface let says:

```
interface House {}
```

```
class AncientHouse implements House {}
```

```
class HouseBuiler
{
    public function __construct(House $house) {}
}
```

If you want to use the `House` interface instead of the exact `AncientHouse` class you need to bind it to the `ServiceProvider` so that the Container can guess that what you want to inject is the `AncientHouse` class.

In the `register()` method inside the `AppServiceProvider`

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind(House::class, AncientHouse::class);
}
```

My english is bad so I hope I explain it properly.

References:

[Service Container](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/container)

[Service Providers](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/providers)